# Actual drag Event.getTarget() hidden by isc_EH_eventMask

Tags: smartclient

My canvas has `canDragResize: true`
then for `dragResizeMove` I'm printing `isc.Event.getTarget()`
But it's only returning some objected with the id `isc_EH_eventMask`

Can anyone shed some light on what that object is? Or how I can get the actual target?